# Why is python deque initialized using the last maxlen items in an iterable?

Tags: python, deque

I was learning how to use deque. Here's what I did:

```
>>> d = deque([1,2,3,4,5,6], maxlen=3)
```

I expected that d would contain [1,2,3]. But instead I got:

```
>>> d
deque([4, 5, 6], maxlen=3)
```

Isn't this counterintuitive?

Comment: If what you want is the first up-to-three values in a list, use `mylist[0:3]`. If you want the same for any iterable object, `itertools.islice(iterable, 3)`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added, a
>   corresponding number of **items are discarded from the opposite end**.
>   Bounded length deques provide functionality similar to the tail filter
>   in Unix. **They are also useful for tracking transactions and other
>   pools of data where only the most recent activity is of interest.**

So, your code is equivalent to:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(maxlen=3)
>>> for i in range(1, 7):
...     d.append(i)
...     print d
...     
deque([1], maxlen=3)
deque([1, 2], maxlen=3)
deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
deque([3, 4, 5], maxlen=3)
deque([4, 5, 6], maxlen=3)
```

Answer (score 4):

The official doc mentioned this clearly:

> Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added, a
>   corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.

Answer (score 1):

It is a design decision. It is more practical to keep more recent elements in the queue. The older are just being poped out from the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, from the docs:

"Returns a new deque object initialized left-to-right (using append()) with data from iterable"

I have mainly used deque objects as buffers for the most recent items. So all the users last 100 actions for example.

Comment: Although I was interested enough to check it and the implementation of `deque` that I'm using (Python 2.7.5) actually doesn't use `append()`. If I subclass and override `append` it doesn't change the behaviour of initialization. This is a subtle point of Python documentation -- "using `append()`" is shorthand for "with the same effect as the defined behaviour of `append()` for this class", it doesn't imply that there's a point of customization there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replying years late, but it sounds like you are questioning the design decision of the `deque` returning `[4, 5, 6]` as opposed to `[1, 2, 3]` when initialized with a `maxlen` of 3.

I do not know exactly why that choice was made, but I can offer a potential reason why:

There is [a recorded talk at Google from a professor going over a philosophy of software design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmSAYlu0NcY). One of the ideas he goes over is that the most common use-case should be the easiest to achieve.

With that philosophy in mind, if you held an assumption that most programmers use the `deque` as a queue, I could see that the `deque` would behave like a queue by default and pop from the opposite end when given more than it's `maxlen`.